# How to center and resize 3d model in browser with three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I would like to build a full page application which will not have any scrolling and therefore I would like to center and resize my 3d model in the middle of my web page at all time no matter what screen size you use.

I have attempted this, but I am getting different centering outputs on different screen size, my code:

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script>

            var scene, camera, renderer , controls, ambientLight, pointLight, textureLoader, map, material, loader;

            function init() {
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                initChris();
                initCamera();
                initRenderer();
                    initControl();
                    render();
            }

            function initCamera() {
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
                    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
                    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
                camera.position.set(0, 0, 2500);
                    camera.add( pointLight );
                    scene.add( camera );
                    scene.add( ambientLight );
                camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            }

            function initRenderer() {
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
                    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
            }

            function initControl(){
                    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
                    controls.enableZoom  = false;
                    controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
                    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
                    controls.update();
            }

            function initChris() {
                textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                map = textureLoader.load('img/CHRIS.jpg');
                material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
                loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                loader.load( 'obj/CHRIS.obj', function ( object ) {
                  object.traverse( function ( node ) {
                    if ( node.isMesh ){
                            node.material = material;
                        }
                  });
                    object.position.y = - window.innerHeight / 2;
                  scene.add( object );
                });
            }

            function onWindowResize(){
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }

            function render() {
                    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }

            init();


        </script>
```

Any help or advise is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you got a screenshot of how this code looks when run? Or an example code demo? 
Also, your object's center of origin might be in the center of its bounding box, so you would need to account for that in your positioning logic too.

Comment: wouldn't object.position.y = - window.innerHeight / 2; fix that though?

Comment: Yes, it would. I meant *might not*. Do you have a code example of this anywhere?